# how to use REST client APIs in embedded system

Tags: python, c

I am using a SDK(runs on ARM M3)  for embedded development and it got ThreadX and Netxduo. I have TCP sockets and HTTP APIs provided in SDK, But as I am new to these I do not have any clue on how to use provided APIs to interface cloud server. So wondering is it possible to integrate/port python to the SDK and use REST API interface to access cloud server. Kindly advice me on how to proceed.. thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> So wondering is it possible to integrate/port python to the SDK

Probably not, at least not with your skillset.

The standard CPython interpreter is not well suited for use in embedded systems. Something like [MicroPython](http://www.micropython.org/) might be more appropriate, but using that will not solve your problem anyway — you would still need to implement code to interface with the APIs provided by your hardware SDK; the only change would be that you would now need to implement that code in the MicroPython interpreter, rather than in your own code. This is likely to be significantly more difficult, as you are not likely to be familiar with the internals of MicroPython.

You will need to learn to use the APIs either way. There's no way around that. Start reading the documentation provided with the SDK.